# Настройка связки nginx + iptables

Tags: nginx, iptables

Есть сервер с установленным nginx, один сетевой интефейс eth0, nginx работает как прокси на 80 порту с контент фильтром. С отключеным фаерволом он отлично работает. Пытаюсь настроить с фаерволом ( ни как не поддается).

```
#! /bin/bashIPT="/sbin/iptables"$IPT -F <br>$IPT -X$IPT -P INPUT DROP $IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT $IPT -P OUTPUT DROPTCP_PORTS="53,80,8443,22"UDP_PORTS="53,21,20"$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT$IPT -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport $TCP_PORTS -j ACCEPT$IPT -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dport $UDP_PORTS -j ACCEPT
```

Подскажите, где может быть моя ошибка? Суть в том, что он должен пускать на 80 порт определенную сеть, но он даж так не заводится. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А не нужно ли выпустить обратно пакеты с `--sport $TCP_PORTS`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы не дали разрешение на открытие нового соединения для цепочки `INPUT` - `--state NEW`
2. Скорее всего для цепочки `OUTPUT` нужно так же открыть ваши порты на выход, указав `--sport` или задав для нее политику по-умолчанию `-P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь всем )))Тут вызвало смех следующее, настраиваем фаервол #! /bin/bashIPT="/sbin/iptables"$IPT -F <br>$IPT -X$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT $IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT $IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPTВот тут у меня уже смех вызвало када так же ничего не заработало!!!!!!Когда я отключаю фаервол все работает, но при отключении (если я не ошибаюсь) политики по умолчанию все аксепт.Тут я тоже самое делаю только включаю его и политики ставлю все аксепт и к моему удивлению почему то ниче не заработало!!!У кого есть еще мысли???

Comment: После того как вы это все запустили из скрипта, вы проверяли политики? Т.е. командой `iptables -L` или `iptables -t filter -L`

Answer (score 0):

Если сервер нагружен слабо, то можно настроить последнее правило

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.0.0/16 --dport 25 \-j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix "outgoing mail"
```

которое будет отправлять в сислог неверные пакеты и последовательно разрешать. Про полностью разрешенный файрвол - покажи еще

```
iptables -nL -t nat
```

Comment: Ваше правило отправляет пакеты в лог, идущие на 25й порт из внутренней сети, причем о неверности пакетов там ни слова. А таблица NAT вам зачем?